# How to Write SOQL as GET method using Salesforce Tooling API On Postman?

Tags: salesforce, postman, apex, salesforce-lightning, tooling

How to fetch SOQL using Salesforce Tooling API using postman?

How To Use Salesforce Typing API to make SOQL behave like REST API call using POSTMAN to access Salesforce object?

As I understand from the below article, i can use Salesforce Typing API to behave like REST API call like GET method to access
SOQL on salesforce objects

Now how do I know the Authentication and Bearer token and what will be request body etc in POSTMAN like basically the entire CURL command for POSTMAN
For Example, if my login id to http://login.salesforce.com is carolyntest@gmail.com and password as password123, how do I convert it to
Auth Token API and then use that token to access Salesforce object using SOQL?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_resource_examples.htm

Thanks in advance
Carolyn

Comment: I think you need to get the token using this : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm

Comment: @Bartheleway please provide your resolution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296542/how-to-create-curl-command-for-post-method-for-salesforce-account-object-using-s